UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-uoESLx/linux-6.8.0/fs/ufs/super.c:1247:19 / pool-thunar[4643]: segfault at 28 ip 00007f30e31322fb
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and I'm not able anymore to copy files from a zfs disk to another one. A big file is copied (or moved) only partially and then the error "the splice of the file has failed" or something like that happens and the copy is aborted. On the dmesg log I see this situation :
[  141.501337] UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-uoESLx/linux-6.8.0/fs/ufs/super.c:1247:19
[  141.501338] shift exponent 36 is too large for 32-bit type 'int'
[  141.501340] CPU: 14 PID: 4255 Comm: mount Tainted: P           O       6.8.0-49-generic #49-Ubuntu
[  141.501342] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z390 AORUS PRO/Z390 AORUS PRO-CF, BIOS F12g GA9 06/08/2020
[  141.501343] Call Trace:
[  141.501344]  <TASK>
[  141.501345]  dump_stack_lvl+0x76/0xa0
[  141.501349]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[  141.501350]  __ubsan_handle_shift_out_of_bounds+0x199/0x370
[  141.501354]  ufs_fill_super.cold+0x16/0x1b7 [ufs]
[  141.501359]  ? sb_set_blocksize+0x1d/0x70
[  141.501362]  ? __pfx_ufs_fill_super+0x10/0x10 [ufs]
[  141.501366]  mount_bdev+0xf3/0x140
[  141.501370]  ufs_mount+0x15/0x30 [ufs]
[  141.501374]  legacy_get_tree+0x28/0x60
[  141.501376]  vfs_get_tree+0x27/0x100
[  141.501377]  do_new_mount+0x1a0/0x340
[  141.501380]  path_mount+0x1e0/0x830
[  141.501382]  ? putname+0x5b/0x80
[  141.501384]  __x64_sys_mount+0x127/0x160
[  141.501386]  x64_sys_call+0x1df5/0x25c0
[  141.501388]  do_syscall_64+0x7f/0x180
[  141.501392]  ? nvme_pci_complete_batch+0xb5/0xe0 [nvme]
[  141.501396]  ? nvme_irq+0x73/0x80 [nvme]
[  141.501400]  ? __pfx_nvme_pci_complete_batch+0x10/0x10 [nvme]
[  141.501403]  ? handle_irq_event+0x52/0x80
[  141.501406]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x7b/0x260
[  141.501407]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  141.501409]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  141.501410]  ? clear_bhb_loop+0x15/0x70
[  141.501412]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x78/0x80
[  141.501413] RIP: 0033:0x7d9f62b2af0e
[  141.501428] Code: 48 8b 0d 0d 7f 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa 49 89 ca b8 a5 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d da 7e 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[  141.501429] RSP: 002b:00007ffde83c8828 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000a5
[  141.501431] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00006393c1406be0 RCX: 00007d9f62b2af0e
[  141.501432] RDX: 00006393c1407070 RSI: 00006393c14070b0 RDI: 00006393c1407090
[  141.501433] RBP: 00007ffde83c8890 R08: 00006393c1407e30 R09: 0000000000000007
[  141.501433] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00006393c1407090
[  141.501434] R13: 00006393c14070b0 R14: 00006393c1407070 R15: 00006393c1406d40
[  141.501436]  </TASK>
[  141.501436] ---[ end trace ]---

[ 1548.597550] pool-thunar[4643]: segfault at 28 ip 00007f30e31322fb sp 00007f30defff928 error 6 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8000.0[7f30e309a000+a0000] likely on CPU 13 (core 5, socket 0)
[ 1548.597592] Code: 75 c5 44 89 33 eb c0 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 31 c0 ba 01 00 00 00 <f0> 0f b1 17 75 01 c3 e9 79 ff ff ff 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55
  
[ 7243.227599] pool-thunar[12876]: segfault at 28 ip 00007cde77a902fb sp 00007cde61fff928 error 6 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8000.0[7cde779f8000+a0000] likely on CPU 13 (core 5, socket 0)

[ 7243.227640] Code: 75 c5 44 89 33 eb c0 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 31 c0 ba 01 00 00 00 <f0> 0f b1 17 75 01 c3 e9 79 ff ff ff 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55

What's happening ? How can I fix it ?
